# How to Track changes in Rich Text Editor?

Tags: devexpress, rich-text-editor

I am planning to use Devexpress Rich Text Editor (ASPxRichEdit). Is it possible to track rich text editor changes history (it means previous changes records has to be backup itself). If yes, how to acheive it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this feature is not yet available in the ASP.NET Rich Edit version (exists in the [WinForms and WPF](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/office/archive/2019/10/21/word-processing-winforms-wpf-office-file-api-track-changes-v19-2.aspx) only).

Try to consult your scenario with the DevExpress Support.